# Hide joyride (intro javascript) for Googlebot

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, cloaking, negative-seo

I am using a joyride script for new visitors. 
Example here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/joyride.html

After the vistior is done with the intro, a cookie will be created and the joyride won't show up again, if the user is using cookies.

I am afraid that Google will index the joyride in every single page and that it might somehow be negative in a SEO perspective.

Is it possible to hide the joyride from Google without getting banned by google. Is this a black hat thing? Would you recommend it? **If not, what do you recommend?**

Comment: Oh no, i thought the flash intro was dead, but it just evolved.

Comment: Use structured markup to clearly delineate content from joyrides, asides and other tangential elements. Do not attempt to hide content from googlebot. Ensure the joyride has no negative impact on users who do not want it, even if they don't persist cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend hiding joyride from Google because google can treat that as **[Cloaking.](https://www.google.hr/search?q=cloacking%20seo&oq=cloacking%20seo&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.1696j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)**

It won't be negative for your SEO if you implement that on your web.

**[How Googlebot Crawls Javascript](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)**

Comment: Does google make some exceptions before they mark something as clocking? Are there any acceptable ways of clocking, or are all things that are hidden from the googlebot marked as something bad by Google? Take my situation for instance.

Comment: well mate, I never use cloaking and google doesn't make an exception.

Answer (score 2):

As far i understand joyride is a piece of html code, which displaying is triggered by a javascript to the news visitors, who doesn't yet have your cookie.

In this case you can easily hide your joyride content from Google without any cloacking.

1. The first idea i would try, is to get all of your joyride textual content into background images, which surely isn't indexed by Google. Thats the simplest thing.
2. Another thing i would try is to bind the javascript behavior, which triggers joyride displaying, to any user action, like scrolling. Google doesn't scroll, so it wouldn't be able to trigger joyride.
3. Yet another thing is worth to try is to put the whole joyride content into a file and show it in an iframe. But the file, containing joyride content, which is iframe src, should be `noindex`-ed. On this way you display your piece of content without indexing it.